# dynamically adjust the width of the dropdown menu based on the sublinks provided in header of shopify dawn theme

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

in the header section of shopify I have added some links and sub links , when I  click on the link I get a drop down which width is occupying's the whole page, I don't want like that I want something like the width should be dynamically adjusted based on the menus/links.

I tried JavaScript code and added it but doesn't work